# Mysql SUM function with join and group by week

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1st Table `Sales`

```
   id   invoice_date      points 
------------------------------------------------
    1    2020-07-01       5
    2    2020-07-01       30
    3    2020-07-02       1
    4    2020-07-03       10
    5    2020-07-04       2.5
    6    2020-07-05       35
    7    2020-07-06       50
    8    2020-07-07       30.5
```

2nd Table `sales_details`

```
id    sales_id      item        mrp     qty 
---------------------------------------------
1        1           A          200     1
2        1           B          300     2
3        2           C          2000    1
4        2           A          200     2
5        2           AB         800     3
6        3           C          2000    1
7        3           D          100     2
8        4           A          200     3
9        5           C          2000    4
10       5           D          100     1
11       6           B          300     1
12       7           A          200     1
13       8           B          300     1
```

I want to query to get result `item` count,`mrp` total,`qty` total from Table `sales_details` and `points` total from Table `sales` by grouping week.
i tried with the following query but getting wrong total of `points` column

```
SELECT sum(B.qty) as item_count,sum(B.mrp*B.qty) as mrp, DATE_ADD( DATE(A.invoice_date), INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK( A.invoice_date )) DAY) week_ending,sum(points) as points from sales A inner join
 sales_details B on A.id=B.sales_id where A.invoice_date>='2020-07-04' and A.invoice_date<='2020-07-07'  GROUP BY week_ending
```

and got the result and the `points` value is wrong

```
item_count   mrp      week_ending        points
-----------------------------------------------
    5        8100      2020-07-04          5
    3        800       2020-07-11         115.5
```

Actual result i want is

```
item_count   mrp      week_ending        points
-----------------------------------------------
    5        8100      2020-07-04          48.5
    3        800       2020-07-11         115.5
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: How do you get 46.5 for week ending 2020-07-04? If I add ids 1-5 up, that is 47.5. However, you are filtering on `A.invoice_date>='2020-07-04'`, which will exclude ids 1-4. Probably you need to filter on week ending date, not the invoice date. Also, you probably need to aggregate the sales_details table before joining it on the sales table.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause includes `A.invoice_date>='2020-07-04' and A.invoice_date<='2020-07-07'` which restricts it to `Sales` records #4-8. The first `GROUP` consists of record #4, which has 2 associated `sales_details` records (#9 and #10) which explains why `SUM(points)` equals 5 (i.e. 2.5 * 2).

Comment: sorry, by mistake. it is 48.5

Answer (score -2):

You just need to check your dates filter. Also I don't think your expected output looks like what you meant.

```
SELECT sum(B.qty) as item_count,sum(B.mrp*B.qty) as mrp, 
       DATE_ADD( DATE(A.invoice_date), INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK( A.invoice_date )) DAY) week_ending,
       sum(points) as points 
FROM sales A  
INNER JOIN sales_details B ON A.id=B.sales_id 
WHERE A.invoice_date>='2020-07-01'  -->Change this date to include all dates of week ending 2020-07-04. You are only including the 4th 
AND A.invoice_date<='2020-07-07'  
GROUP BY week_ending
```

Comment: sorry, by mistake. i want 48.5. now i edited in question